# Pandas - Apply aggregation on filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

GroupBy a column and aggregate one of the columns on filtered values.

Like in the given example below, I want to count the number of animals which are of gender 'male' for each of the 'kind' of animals

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'kind': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog'],
                'height': [9.1, 6.0, 9.5, 34.0],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female']})
df.groupby('kind').agg({'height': 'min', 'gender': lambda g: (g == 'male').count()})
```

Output that I get (which is wrong)

```
kind      height     gender
cat       9.1        2
dog       6.0        2
```

Expected output:

```
kind      height     gender
cat       9.1        1
dog       6.0        0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of count(), you can use sum().

```
df.groupby('kind').agg({'height': 'min', 'gender': lambda g: (g == 'male').sum()})
```